# Unusual action of $\text{SL}(2,\Bbb Z)$. Finding the invariant subspaces.

Tags: linear-algebra, elementary-number-theory, group-actions, integer-lattices

I recently came across to the following action of $\text{SL}(2,\Bbb Z)$ on the space $\Bbb R^n\times\Bbb R^n$ defined as
$$ 
\begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d
\end{pmatrix}\cdot \big(v,\,w\big)\mapsto \big(dv-cw,\,-bv+aw\big)=\big(v,\,w\big)
\begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d
\end{pmatrix}^{-1}
$$ where $v=(v_1,\dots,v_n),\, w=(w_1,\dots,w_n)\in \Bbb R^n$.

I would like to determine the $\text{SL}(2,\Bbb Z)$-invariant closed subsets.

**Some examples**

Of course the trivial subspaces $\{0\}$ and $\Bbb R^n\times\Bbb R^n$ are among these. One can easily check that every linear subspace of the form $V\times V$, where $V<\Bbb R^n$ is invariant under these action. On the other hand, if $V,W<\Bbb R^n$ are different subspaces, then $V\times W$ is not invariant.
Similarly, if $\Lambda$ is any lattice in $\Bbb R^n$, then $\Lambda\times\Lambda$ is also invariant.

Not only, considering $\Bbb R^n\times\Bbb R^n$ as $\Bbb R^2\times\cdots\times\Bbb R^2$, where $\big(v,\,w\big)$ is identified with $\big(\big(v_1,\,w_1\big),\dots,\big(v_n,\,w_n\big)\big)$, if $\Lambda$ is a lattice in $\Bbb R^2$, the $n$-times product $\Lambda\times\cdots\times\Lambda$ is $\text{SL}(2,\Bbb Z)$-invariant.

These are some examples of invariant closed subspaces I have found so far. I would like to determine all of them.

*In particular I am interested in those which are also subgroups of $\Bbb R^n\times \Bbb R^n$*.

Any idea, hint or reference is very appreciated!

Comment: `$\left(\right)$` for the output $\left(\left(\frac{\text{sth}}{\text{sth}}\right)^{\text{sth}}\right)$ instead of `$\big(\big)$`

Comment: Just a minor remark: a lattice is not a vector subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}^n$. Do you want to find all invariant subgroups?

Comment: @Learning sure. With "subspaces" I meant topological subspace. That's the reason why I was thinking about lattices also.

Comment: @Learning yes, right. I am mainly interested on those which are also subgroups.